# How does the model_path() method work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and have been playing with some open source code in order to learn.

I am having some issues understanding what the `model_path(@model)` method returns and how to change it. Specifically, I have a model with an `id` and a `slug` and for some reason `model_path(@model)` always returns the path with the `slug` and not the `id`.

Any ideas on why this may be and how I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model_path(@model)
```

will produce this URL

```
/model/:id
```

it will substitute `:id` with whatever `@model.to_param` returns

Comment: Thanks! Code makes more sense now. Is there an easy way to generate a http://domain.com/:id/:slug

Comment: add a custom route. match '/:id/:slug', :to => "your_controller#show", :as => :custom_model. Then you can use this in your views custom_model_path(@model.id, @model.slug). But I don't find this a good solution, better make the to_param method return the id and a slug so the url will be like this "/model/12-blabla"

Comment: I like the 12-blablah also, but then isn't it more difficult for the controller to user with params[:id]? It would need to parse out either the slug or the id, in order to find the model instance, right?

Comment: If you are using MySQL, then no parsing is needed. Works out of the box with such parameters